# Determine what GC.Collect() is Collecting

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

I have a console program written in VB.NET (.NET 4.5.2) that acts as a service. A continuous loop runs, and then waits for a message on an MSMQ queue, and processes the message. Somehow this program has a substantial memory leak. I have gone through all the code and done everything I could to use Using statements, but yet the problem persists.  The more times through the loop, the higher the memory used by the program, and this memory is never reclaimed by the garbage collector.

I ended up putting a GC.Collect() at the bottom of my loop, and was able to free up most of the memory.  However, I realize that this is bad practice and could cause issues.  Just wondering if there is a way to inspect what variables the GC.Collect() is getting rid of, so I can find the root of the problem?

```
Do While (True)
    ' Code to wait for message on a queue
    ' Code to process message (includes calls to class library)
    GC.Collect()
Loop
```

Comment: memory leaks are most likely due to the code not releasing / disposing of objects they created, properly. so nobody can tell where your going wrong in regards to `GC` being called.. can you do a global search on where you are creating new instances of particular objects

Comment: Maybe GC sees no reasons to run. Do you actually experience a problem (like out of memory exception) or you just worry that memory grows but no actual problem?

Comment: I suspect you will get to the problem sooner if you cut your code down (piece by piece) until the leak appears to stop. Then whatever you last removed must be the culprit.

Comment: You would want to use a .NET Memory Profiler, there are plenty of products.  Newer versions of Visual Studio also come with a memory profiler (Enterprise / Ultimate versions I believe).  I've used JetBrains dotMemory and RedGate Ants Memory profilers.

Comment: The only issue with inducing garbage collection is that of a potential performance hit, hence the "general purpose" advice is to the GC handle itself.  [Read up on .NET GC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/garbage-collection/index).  Sometimes you just have to call GC.Collect, if you find your rate of allocations is too fast (but then again might be better to avoid so many allocs in the first place).  Tradeoffs tradeoffs.

Comment: Yes - We had a production issue where the process started at consuming 6.3 MB of memory, and within a couple of weeks (and many thousands of messages), it had increased to several GB of memory, and caused the server to be unresponsive.

Answer (score 2):

If the garbage collector is freeing memory when you manually invoke it, you are not leaking memory. A leak in a managed memory environment is memory that the GC can't free because it is referenced somewhere on the object graph.

It could be that they way your code uses objects instances that are being promoted to gen1, gen2 or the large object heap. Instances in these generations are collected less frequently then gen0. The windows resource monitor includes a number of [performance counters that can be used to profile the behavior of the managed heap](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x2tyfybc(v=vs.110).aspx). I would guess that you might have objects being promoted into gen2. Tracking the "Gen 1 Promoted Bytes/Sec" counter would give you insight as to whether this is what's happening.

In a managed memory environment the GC runs when there is memory pressure, not when object instances are no longer needed, so the mere presence of increased memory use is not necessarily the sign of a leak.

If you take the `Collect` out does memory usage always increase (say over a number of minutes or messages being processed form the queue), or does it go up and down somewhat like a sin wave? If it's the latter just let the GC do its thing, you don't have a leak.

- Visual studio has a number of memory analysis features https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn342825.aspx
- The SOS managed debugger extension is a very powerful tool for sifting through the managed heap, though it is not for the faint of heart. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/tools/sos-dll-sos-debugging-extension

Comment: To answer your question - If I take the Collect out  the memory usage will always increase as I process more and more messages. If I start running the process and there are no messages in the queue, it will start at 6.3 MB of memory used. If I throw 1000 messages in the queue it will begin processing them. By the time it is done, the memory use will have doubled, and it will stay that way even though there are no new messages in the queue to process.

Comment: @DavidP I'd start with the linked article about performance counters to see into which generations your allocations are going. The GC won't necessarily run just because the process is idle. I'd set up a test scenario whereby you continuously feed items into the queue in order to get the GC to run (Collections can also be tracked with performance counters)